# Changing text and color randomly

Tags: javascript, random

I try to write a code that puts on the screen random texts and change the color sometimes( in loop 2).

I don't understand why my code loops just once. It seems that the show() function works by itself but the test() loop doesn't run well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    window.onload=function(){
        button.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            test();
        });
}//]]> 

function show() {
    b=makeid();
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = b;
}  

function test() {
    var div = document.getElementById('text');
    for (i=0;i<5;i++) {b=makeid();
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = b;
        if (i==2) {div.style.color = '#000000';}
        setTimeout(function(){ show();},500);
        if (i==2) {div.style.color = '#CC0000';}
    }
}

function makeid() {
    var text = "";
    var possible =     "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for( var i=0; i < 2; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    return text;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button">click</button>
    <div>
        <span id="text"></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code only changes to same color always,so you won't be able to see different colors anytime in your output

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, I have tried to achieve your requirement as close as possible by my understanding of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your Code is not sufficient for what you are trying to achieve

**Issue with your code:-**

You were calling `show()` function with a fixed timeout, so even though the function waits, all it's instances gets called at once after the same time period.

And you don't get to see the change in text with your eyes.

**In case of color:-** 
You were always changing the color to same color, so it was always a single color in output.

**I have achieved your requirement. Try this:-**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload=function(){
 button.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
 test();
});

} 

function show()
{
 b=makeid();
 document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = b;

}  

function test()
{
   var div = document.getElementById('text');
   var repeat = setInterval(function(){ 
        div.style.color = getRandomColor();
        show();
      },500);
      
   setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(repeat);},2500);
}

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function makeid()
{
  var text = "";
  var possible =     "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
 for( var i=0; i < 2; i++ )
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
 return text;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
 <button id="button">click</button>
 <div>
  <span id="text"></span>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Is this the only way to do it or is there also a sleep functionality?

Comment: @OMGsh, no there is no sleep functionality in javascript. JavaScript only has 2 timings functions, `setInterval()` & `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Now want also to store the texts and the colors. But If I use in the loop 

b[i]=makeid();
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = b[i];},500+i*500);

when the setTimeout is processed the b[i] has already changed

Comment: @OMGsh ok.. great

Comment: @OMGsh if your query is resolved & your are satisfied with my answer, then please mark it as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can add 'console' in front of 'show', you can see the loop run 5 times;then you can see how 'setTimeout' work ,you will know why